Cumulative feature importance in Random Forest taking into account past days data
I have a dataframe with past days data and current day data. Example columns [ cases , mobility, temp , rh , cases_1, mobility_1 , temp_1 , rh_1, cases_2, mobility_2, temp_2, rh_2 and so on. . ]. My target column (Y) is ‘cases’ and col_i denotes the parameters i days before the current day.
I applied k fold cross validation random forest using all parameters except target as input and then found the feature importance. Can I add the feature importances of a particular parameter over past days to find its cumulative feature importance. eg( cumulative feature importance of rh = feature importance of (rh + rh_1 + rh_2 . . . )).
I tried applying random forest to predict the current day cases. But the feature importance is not how we expected.
